# GSL Polar Complex Numbers Appear to be extremely different

Tags: c, complex-numbers, gsl

Using [`minunit.h`](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html) to test built-in gsl structs.

I have written the following test:

```
static
char * test_gsl_polar_complex_number_struct()
{
  double r = 0.325784;
  double theta = 0.421329;

  gsl_complex test_polr_complex_number = gsl_complex_polar ( r, theta ); 

  printf("expected r: %f, actual r: %f\n", r, GSL_REAL(test_polr_complex_number));
  mu_assert("real part of polar complex number does not match expected", 
  GSL_REAL(test_polr_complex_number) == r);

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting a failing test with the following output:

```
expected r: 0.325784, actual r: 0.297293
expected theta: 0.421329, actual theta: 0.133237
real part of polar complex number does not match expected
```

It is of note that the exact same test executes without errors on the rectangular complex struct.

Comment: Investigating in `gsl-complex.h`, the `GSL_REAL` macro is defined as:               `#define GSL_REAL(z)     ((z).dat[0])`

Comment: The code you presented *did not* produce the output you presented.  Not all of it, anyway.

Comment: If we *must* get into semantics, I clearly stated that I wrote a test and that the test failed. I never said, "the code I wrote."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong expectations.  The function `gsl_complex_polar()` initializes a complex number from components given in polar complex form:

> This function returns the complex number z = r \exp(i \theta) = r (\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)) from the polar representation (r,theta)

([GSL documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Representation-of-complex-numbers.html#Representation-of-complex-numbers))

That's fine, but the `GSL_REAL()` macro returns the real part of a complex number.  That's not the same thing as the `r` component of the polar representation.  In fact, the docs I already quoted tell you exactly what it is: `r cos(theta)`.